# How to change the Discount label in magento Invoice

Tags: magento, pdf, invoice

When I installed magento I chose US English and run my store with it for quite some time. Later I had some issues with the date and time so I had to change the locale option to UK_English. Now I want to change the Discount label to Special Discount in Pdf invoice but changing the label with translate.csv doen't work also I don't know whether changing the en_US would work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change it/add it to your locale directory in Mage_Sales.csv.

```
"Discount","Special Discount"
"Discount (%s)","Special Discount (%s)"
```

Upload it, flush your translation cache and you should be golden.

Comment: are you using the standard Magento pdf invoice functionality or do you have a pdf module installed?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it. I created a translate.csv file and place it in newly created folder named en_GB in app-locale. Now I do the changes as I want and it works.;D